# instrumented method with javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I'm trying to write the name of the method into a file by adding few lines of code into each instrumented methods. I'm using Javassist.

Here's my code:

```
public static void addInstrumentation(CtClass ctClass, CtMethod ctMethod) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    if (ctClass.getName().startsWith("com.application.bookstore.entities.test")) {
        String testName = ctClass.getName() + "." + ctMethod.getName();
        String fileToWrite = "C:/profiler/root.txt";
        ctMethod.insertBefore("{ FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(\"" + fileToWrite + "\", true); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); out.write(\"" + testName + "\"); out.newLine(); out.close(); }");
    }
    else {
        String methodName = ctClass.getName() + "." + ctMethod.getName() + "()";
        String fileToRead = "C:/profiler/root.txt";
        ctMethod.insertBefore("{ FileReader fr = new FileReader(\"" + fileToRead + "\"); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr); String line; while((line = in.readLine()) != null); in.close();  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(line, true); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); out.write(\"" + methodName + "\"); out.newLine(); out.close(); }");
    }
}



/**
 * Get current classname and for each methods inside it, call the addInstrumentation method.
 */
@Override
public void onLoad(ClassPool pool, String classname) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    if (classToImplement(classname))
    {
        pool.importPackage("java.io");
        CtClass ctClass = pool.get(classname);          


        for (CtMethod ctMethod : ctClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
           if (!Modifier.isNative(ctMethod.getModifiers())) {
               addInstrumentation(ctClass, ctMethod);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in the else part. I can't get the value of line and so open the file and write into it.

So, have you an idea about how to retrieve the value of line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `static String` and keep the last value of `testName`. For a single thread you'll get the same result. For multiple threads it's a different story, but I guess that you're trying to get the stack trace for your tests and you run it sequential, so you should be safe.
E.g.:

Let's say you have a class

```
com.application.bookstore.entities.test.ClassWithTheStaticField
```

which has:

```
public static String lastTestMethod;
```

You can modify `addInstrumentation` like this:

```
public static void addInstrumentation(CtClass ctClass, CtMethod ctMethod) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    if (ctClass.getName().startsWith("com.application.bookstore.entities.test")) {
        String testName = ctClass.getName() + "." + ctMethod.getName();
        String fileToWrite = "C:/profiler/root.txt";
        ctMethod.insertBefore("{ com.application.bookstore.entities.test.ClassWithTheStaticField.lastTestMethod = " + testName + "; FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(\"" + fileToWrite + "\", true); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); out.write(\"" + testName + "\"); out.newLine(); out.close(); }");
    }
    else {
        String methodName = ctClass.getName() + "." + ctMethod.getName() + "()";
        String fileToRead = "C:/profiler/root.txt";
        ctMethod.insertBefore("{ FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(com.application.bookstore.entities.test.ClassWithTheStaticField.lastTestMethod, true); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); out.write(\"" + methodName + "\"); out.newLine(); out.close(); }");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks, In fact, my code worked fine. Juste line was null because of the nextLine() put before... just needed to correct the while(). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I thought that you don't like the fact that you have to parse the whole file every time to get the last line.

Comment: I keep your code in mind if I a performance issue. Thanks again!